# Что означает данный код?

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом ниже.

Я новичок и только недавно начал познавать программирование.

**Список переменных и их значений:**

```
$slideMenu = '';
$slides = array(
  array(
    'background' => 'image',
    'h2' => 'Text',
    'text' => 'Text'
  ),
  array(
    'background' => 'image',
    'h2' => 'Text',
    'text' => 'Text'
  ),
  array(
    'background' => 'image',
    'h2' => 'Text',
    'text' => 'Text'
  ),
);
```

А далее, вот:

```
<?php foreach ($slides as $i => $slide) { ?>
    <div id="slide-<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" class="slide" style="display: <?php echo($i > 0 ? 'none' : 'block'); ?>;background-image: url(<?php echo $slide['background'] ?>);">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="width: 40%;color: #fff;" class="col">
                <div style="padding: 0 15px;">
                    <h2><?php echo $slide['h2'] ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $slide['text'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $slideMenu .= '<a href="#" data-slide-id="' . ($i + 1) . '" data-rel="#slide-' . ($i + 1) . '" class="' . ($i == 0 ? 'current' : '') . '"></a>'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Не совсем понятны вот эти части:

```
<div id="slide-<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" class="slide" style="display: <?php echo($i > 0 ? 'none' : 'block'); ?>;background-image: url(<?php echo $slide['background'] ?>);">

<?php $slideMenu .= '<a href="#" data-slide-id="' . ($i + 1) . '" data-rel="#slide-' . ($i + 1) . '" class="' . ($i == 0 ? 'current' : '') . '"></a>'; ?>
```

Comment: До какого уровня Вам нужно разказывать? до объяснений что такое for и if?

Comment: Честно говоря, вопрос похож на поиск пояснений по домашнему заданию.

Comment: Нет, совсем не д/з :)
Просто я только начинаю свой путь программиста и многие моменты в тех или иных вещах немного не понимаю.
Вы ведь тоже когда-то были новичками. Поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($slides as $i => $slide) { ?>
```

Создает цикл по всем элементам `$slides`. При каждом проходе цикла будут существовать 2 элемента `$i` - индекс, `$slide` - массив значений `array('h2' => "значение", 'text' => "значение", ...);`

---

```
<div id="slide-<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" class="slide" style="display: <?php echo($i > 0 ? 'none' : 'block'); ?>;background-image: url(<?php echo $slide['background'] ?>);">
```

Создается блок, где генерируются атрибуты: `id = slide + наш индекс с каждым проходом цикла` (будет такое: `id="slide-1", id="slide-2", id="slide-3"...`). Тоже самое и с атрибутом `data-id`. И проверка в конце, на не нулевой `$i`. Если ты в первом элементе то у блока будет `display: block`, иначе `display: none`;

---

```
<h2><?php echo $slide['h2'] ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $slide['text'] ?></p>
```

Просто выводятся 2 значения из массива `$slide`

---

```
<?php $slideMenu .= '<a href="#" data-slide-id="' . ($i + 1) . '" data-rel="#slide-' . ($i + 1) . '" class="' . ($i == 0 ? 'current' : '') . '"></a>'; ?>
```

Дописывает в переменную `$slideMenu` ссылку с `data-` атрибутами. Видимо генерирует количество точек (переключателей) по количеству слайдов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь в разъяснений!

Comment: @Z.Zum пометь тогда вопрос как правильный, если ты все понял, и он отвечает на твой вопрос